# How to design a class containing related member variables efficiently?

Tags: python, oop

Suppose I want a class named Num which contains a number, its half, and its square.

I should be able to modify any of the three variables and it will affects all of its related member variables. I should be able to instantiate the class with any of the three value.

What is the best way to design this class so that it can be modified easily and ensure that I will not leave something behind?

Should I store all the three numbers or just store the main number?

For example, this is how I will use my class in Python:

```
num = Num(5)
print num.n, num.half, num.square
```

And it should print 5, 2.5 and 25

That's simple but I also want to initialize with its half.

```
num = Num(half=2.5)
print num.n, num.half, num.square
```

And it should also print 5, 2.5 and 25

How can I make the init function know that it's a half?

And I also want to modify any of the number and it will change all related numbers! E.g.:

```
num.square = 100
print num.n, num.half, num.square
```

And it should print 10, 5 and 100.

How can I design the class?

Comment: You could use keyword arguments; `num = Num(half=2.5)`. It's impossible without explicitly specifying what the number is. Also use properties to support setters.

Comment: what should `n = 2.38` output?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That's good. But how can I deal with situation such as Num(n=2, half=4,square=0) ? Or just not do it when coding?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham As Colonel said, you should specify the keyword name. The statement I wrote is wrong.

Comment: @off99555, so you are passing by keyword not just passing `n`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's right.

Comment: ```efficiently``` can be a pretty subjective term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same solution as @Daniel - *expanded*, lambda-less, Python 3.3:

```
class Num:
#class Num(object): for Python 2.
    def __init__(self, n = None, half = None, square = None):
        if n is not None:
            self.n = n
        elif half is not None:
            self.half = half
        elif square is not None:
            self.square = square
        else:
            self.n = 0

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.__n
    @n.setter
    def n(self, n):
        self.__n = n
    @property
    def half(self):
        return self.n / 2.0
    @half.setter
    def half(self, n):
        self.n = n * 2
    @property
    def square(self):
        return self.n ** 2
    @square.setter
    def square(self, n):
        self.n = n ** .5

>>> five = Num(n=5)
>>> five.half, five.n, five.square, five._Num__n
(2.5, 5, 25, 5)
>>>
```

Comment: Does this work in python 2.7?
I run your code with
n = Num(5)
print n.n and it error AttributeError: Num instance has no attribute '_Num__n'

Comment: @off99555 - change the first line of the class definition, see the inline comment. Note this is essentially the same solution as Daniel 's.

Comment: well that works! thank you. This look a lot more readable. My new knowledge about related variables!

Comment: @off99555 - perhaps Daniels is *efficient* for writing and mine is *efficient* for reading.

Comment: @off99555: beware of `self.n / 2` results in different values for Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @wii: don't use double underscore, it's not needed here. You don't set `__n` if no parameter is given in `__init__`. Why do you set `__n` through the property for all setters?

Comment: @Daniel - I used the double underscore prefix to *invoke* the name-mangling feature - an attempt to prevent accidentally changing the *underlying* value of the object.  Probably out of habit, certainly no deep thought went into it.  Why is it wrong?

Comment: If I have class A(object) and B(A), would B be a new style class that can use property?

Comment: @off99555: every class in Python 2 that is a subclass of `object` is a new style class. B is subclass of A is subclass of objects: so, yes.

Comment: @wii: next unintuitive point: `Num(5)` is not what everyone expects.

Comment: I chose your answer because I like the way you still use encapsulated 'n' in half and square properties rather than using '_n' which is not provident enough..

Comment: @Daniel , there I go not thinking again - fixed.

Comment: @Daniel - I guess I don't understand. Is there a requirement to *create* all instance variables/attributes in ```__init__```?

Answer (score 4):

You need properties, to set or get any of your values. The different behavior of `__init__` can be achieved with keyword arguments:

```
class Num(object):
    def __init__(self, n=None, half=None, square=None):
        self._n = 0
        if n is not None:
            self.n = n
        if half is not None:
            self.half = half
        if square is not None:
            self.square = square

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self._n

    @n.setter
    def n(self, n):
        self._n = n

    @property
    def half(self):
        return self._n * 0.5

    @half.setter
    def half(self, n):
        self._n = n * 2

    @property
    def square(self):
        return self._n ** 2

    @square.setter
    def square(self, n):
        self._n = n ** 0.5

n = Num(square=100)
print n.half
```

EDIT: now without lambdas, gives a nice default value, when no value is given at initalization, and does not result in `AttributeError`s otherwise.

Comment: That's very confusing but look very interesting! I'm going to look into lessons about properties.

Comment: Why did you choose to use lambdas?

Comment: That wasn't a criticism, I actually want to know why.

Comment: @wwii: to keep the definition of `n`, `half` and `square` together.

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach, you could apply the logic in `__setattr__`:

```
class Num(object):
    def __init__(self, n=None, half=None, square=None):
        if all(arg is None for arg in (n, half, square)):
            raise ValueError("Must supply at least one arg.")
        if n is not None:
            self.n = n
        elif half is not None:
            self.half = half
        elif square is not None:
            self.square = square

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        dct = self.__dict__
        if key == "n":
            dct[key] = value
            dct["half"] = value / 2.
            dct["square"] = value ** 2
        elif key == "half":
            dct[key] = value
            dct["n"] = value * 2
            dct["square"] = self.n ** 2
        elif key == "square":
            dct[key] = value
            dct["n"] = value ** .5
            dct["half"] = self.n / 2.
        else:
            dct[key] = value
```

Comment: Is that what ```property``` does *behind-the-scenes*?